# onKeyPress of input box(in html) call servlet without changing url in address bar of browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box in html form and onKeyPress of that box I need to search for the text in that input text box using servlet same as google does. But when I press enter key, the url in the address bar of browser changes and request is not sent to servlet. What can be done to avoid this?

Input text box in HTML file

```
<input type="text" id="query" name="query" size="45" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event)">
```

SearchKeyPress(e) code

```
function searchKeyPress(e)
    {
        if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            createHttpRequest();
        }
    }
```

createHttpRequest is used to call servlet SearchService:

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/final_project/SearchService?user_query="+getQueryString();

        request.onreadystatechange = handleSearchResult;
        request.open("GET",url,true);

        request.send(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script :

```
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
    createHttpRequest();
    return false;
}
```

and your html to this

```
onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event)"
```

this will prevent the form being submitted

Comment: thanks a lot. This is working fine. But can u just explain how does it work this way??

Comment: the `return false` prevents the default action from happening - you stop the form from submitting

Comment: this is also the answer to your other question on SO that is unanswered ! - replace `return true` with `return false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of submitting the form. Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).